Grouping numbers in Powershell
I have an Array of string. For example:
Array[0] = ‘4’
Array[1] = ‘7’
Array[2] = ‘8‘
Array[3] = ‘9‘
Array[4] = ‘10‘
Array[5] = ‘21‘
Array[6] = ‘25‘
Array[7] = ‘26‘
Array[8] = ‘27‘

How can I group the numbers this way?
Array[0] = “4”
Array[1] = “7..10”
Array[2] = “21”
Array[3] = “25..27”

Is there a powershell function?
Tanks!

is the array always pre-sorted?

Yes, it is always pre-sorted.

Do you want the resulting array to be strings?

If this is possible, that would be good.

This is one way to do it, see inline comments to follow the logic.
$Array = @(
    '4'
    '7'
    '8'
    '9'
    '10'
    '21'
    '25'
    '26'
    '27'
)

$startRange = $null
$ranges = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Array.Length; $i++) {
    # get the array element and convert to int
    $value = [int] $Array[$i]
    # if the next array element is not equal to this array element + 1
    if ($Array[$i + 1] -ne $value + 1) {
        # if we had captured the start of a sequence before
        if ($null -ne $startRange) {
            # output the sequence
            "$startRange..$value"
            # and reset this variable
            $startRange = $null
        }
        else {
            # else, there was no sequence before, output as is
            "$value"
        }

        # and go to next iteration
        continue
    }

    # else, the next array element is equal to this value + 1
    # if $startRange is null
    if (-not $startRange) {
        # capture the start of a sequence
        $startRange = $value
    }
}

$ranges


n alternative to Santiago's answer.
Probably less efficient
$NumbrsArray = @(
    '4'
    '7'
    '8'
    '9'
    '10'
    '21'
    '25'
    '26'
    '27'
)

$NewCollection = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$index = 0


foreach ($LoopNumber in $NumbrsArray) {
    if ($null -eq $NewCollection[$index]) {
        $NewCollection.add($LoopNumber)
        continue
    }
    
    
    $TempValue = $NewCollection[$index] -replace '^\d+(\.\.)?'

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($TempValue)) {
        $TempValue = $NewCollection[$index]   
    }

    if ([int]$TempValue + 1 -eq [int]$LoopNumber) {
        $NewCollection[$index] = $NewCollection[$index] -replace '^(\d+)(\.\.\d+)?$', "`$1..$LoopNumber"
    }
    else {
        $NewCollection.add($LoopNumber)
        $index++
    }
}

$NewCollection

